# Do openshift ENV variables scale?

Tags: openshift

I'm running a 3 gear env in Openshift using Wildfly cartridges with scaling enabled.

If I run the following command to create a custom env variable, will it be copied when the app is scaled? :

```
rhc env set <Variable>=<Value> -a App_Name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the developer center [[1]](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/environment-variables.html#custom-variables) you don't need to recreate the variable on app restart, so you should be safe for scaling as well, as it is just another spawned gear.